# Multiple loops in simple SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, loops, while-loop

This is a theoretical question. I would like to know, if something like following is possible:

Let's say we have a table with items, 99 storage sites and bunch of other data. We want to filter out only few of them, bases on conditions in the following select statement:

```
select
    Id,
    Item,
    Site1, Site2..., Site99
from 
    Sites 
where
    (Site1 is not null and Site1 <> 'NY')
    or (Site2 is not null and Site2 <> 'NY')
    or ...
    or (Site99 is not null and Site99 <> 'NY')
```

Is there a way to loop Site1 -> 99 in statement and condition instead of typing it manually?

Comment: If `Site1` is null, `Site1 <>'NY'` will be false. You could just write `Site1<>'NY' OR Site2<>'NY' ... `.

Comment: This a questionable model.  What happens if you add a site, or close one?  Your database and all related queries, objects, and applications need fixing.  Site should be a single column and populated with the site number.  This will make your query considerably easier and have many other benefits as well.

Comment: Please don’t design a table this way.

Comment: Actually, this table doesn't exists. I created this example just to see if something like this is possible, because there are some dbo's in our CRM with 3 eMails or 3 telephone numbers, and i thought that it would'nt be so demonstrative example. I don't design tables, just sometimes read from them. Anyway, thank you for feedback.

Comment: But there is a way...

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to loop Site1 -> 99 in statement and condition instead
>   of typing it manually?

Only with Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tally table...

```
WITH
E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
cte(N) AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
)

select '(Site' + cast(N as varchar) + ' IS NOT NULL and Site' + cast(N as varchar) + ' <> ''NY'')' +  case when N != 99 then ' OR' else '' end
from cte
where N < 100
```

Then copy this out and paste it to your query.